# SWRevealViewController toggle not working with custom Navigation Bar Button

Tags: ios, swift, swrevealviewcontroller

I am using SWRevealViewController to show a side menu in Swift 2.0 I have downloaded the files from GitHub, created the bridging header and connected segues correctly. I am creating a custom button but the action "reveal toggle" is not firing. Where am I making a mistake?

```
super.viewDidLoad()
    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.topItem?.title = "DASHBOARD"
    self.navigationController!.navigationBar.tintColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
    self.navigationController!.navigationBar.titleTextAttributes =
        [NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.whiteColor()]
    self.navigationController!.navigationBar.titleTextAttributes = [ NSFontAttributeName: UIFont(name: "Teko-Regular", size: 26)!]
    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.barTintColor = UIColor.redColor()
    let btnName = UIButton()
    btnName.setImage(UIImage(named: "LeftNavItem"), forState: .Normal)
    btnName.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 20, 20)

    let leftBarButton = UIBarButtonItem()
    leftBarButton.customView = btnName
    self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = leftBarButton
    if self.revealViewController() != nil {
        //print(self.revealViewController())
        leftBarButton.target = self.revealViewController()
        leftBarButton.action = Selector("revealToggle:")

        self.view.addGestureRecognizer(self.revealViewController().panGestureRecognizer())
    }
```

The gesture recognizer is firing properly, but not the "revealToggle:" What's the mistake?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
class Name: SWRevealViewControllerDelegate

override func viewDidLoad() {
  super.viewDidLoad()

   self.revealViewController().delegate = self

}
```

Comment: It's the correct answer. Only a slight note that "UIBarButton" has no member ".addTarget" You have to do this on "UIButton" and then add that button as a subview to "UIBarButton"

Answer (score 0):

I was facing same issues using SWRevealViewController.
Solution :**After Login i was calling dashboard screen before But now 
i replaced with SWrevealviewcontroller like below code.that's it now working fine

```
 let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
                let viewController1 =
                    storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "SWRevealViewController") as! SWRevealViewController
                self.present(viewController1, animated: true,completion: nil)
```

*Add below code in viewdidload() method

```
 if revealViewController() != nil {
        menuoutlet.target = self.revealViewController()
         menuoutlet.action = #selector(SWRevealViewController.revealToggle(_:))
        self.view.addGestureRecognizer(revealViewController().panGestureRecognizer())
        self.revealViewController().rearViewRevealWidth = 240
    }
```

**Menu button action code**

```
  @IBAction func menu(_ sender: Any) {
    let btntitle = (sender as AnyObject).currentTitle!
    self.revealViewController().rearViewController.performSegue(withIdentifier: btntitle!, sender: self.revealViewController().rearViewController)
}
```

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). You can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/19729245)

Comment: I got solution @SRack